# How do I use a regular expression to split this string '-25+26+78-21' to get -25,26,78, -21?

Tags: java, regex

How do I use a regular expression to split this string '-25+26+78-21' to get -25,26,78, -21?

Comment: So you're just splitting on a `+`?

Comment: yes.But the hard part is that the minus sign in -25 is not the operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
    //your input
    String numbers = "-25+26+78-21";
    //split lookahead by + or - and store them in array of strings
    //you can do with it afterwards whatever you like, turn it into ints for example
    String[] tokens = numbers.split("(?=\\-)|\\+");
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(tokens));
```

Comment: That prints `[-25, +26, +78, -21]`, not the desired `-25, 26, 78, -21`. Changing to `split("(?=\\-)|\\+")` would do the trick, i.e. the `+` should be consumed by the split.

Comment: @Andreas I just wanted to write the same. Yes, this should do the trick. Nice, Andreas.

Comment: @yang If it answers the question, please consider accepting it as the answer by clicking on the check next to the answer. This awards the poster reputation points, and it makes it clear to future readers that the answer fixed the problem so that if they have a similar issue they can try it too.

Comment: I just started using stackoverflow, something I don't understand yet.Thanks for your advice

Comment: @yang If you agree with answer there is ✓ beneath Number for rating answer. Mark/Click it so that your question and my answer get accepted.